# having count(~) > 1 doesn't remove as expected

Tags: sql, db2

**I have this query:**

```
select cast(A.when as date) as purchase_date, A.id 
from purchase A
group by cast(A.when as date), A.id order by A.id
```

**result:**

```
PURCHASE_DATE ID
------------- ------
04/20/1999         1
12/01/2001         1
08/08/1998         2
02/13/1999         2
04/16/1999         2
02/23/2001         2
04/24/2001         2
10/21/2001         2
12/01/2001         2
01/27/1998         3
10/06/2001         3
06/13/2000         4
06/30/2001         4
08/11/2001         4
07/17/2001         5
```

**What I want to do:**

What I want to do is removing cids and its purchase_date from above result that has only one cid and only one purchase_date. So in the above result, I want to remove 1 row for cid 5.

**Thus, I ran following query:**

```
select B.id, B.purchase_date from (select cast(A.when as date) as
purchase_date, A.id from purchase A group by cast(A.when as date),
A.id order by A.id) B group by B.id, B.purchase_date having
count(B.id) > 1
```

You will see that first query I suggested at the top of this page become a sub-query of above query and I tried to remove any row that has only 1 id using "having count(B.id) > 1", but is failed.

**Here is result:**

```
ID    PURCHASE_DATE
------ -------------

  0 record(s) selected.

enter code here
```

I thought "having count(B.id) > 1" would remove any rows that has only one id, but it doesn't. How can I do this?

**Expected result should be like:**

```
ID    PURCHASE_DATE
------ -------------
     1 04/20/1999
     1 12/01/2001
     2 08/08/1998
     2 02/13/1999
     2 04/16/1999
     2 02/23/2001
     2 04/24/2001
     2 10/21/2001
     2 12/01/2001
     3 01/27/1998
     3 10/06/2001
     4 06/13/2000
     4 06/30/2001
     4 08/11/2001
```

only id with 5 should be removed.

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: @scaisEdge  i guess db2, it is called db2

Comment: then removed  mysql tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by ID only, not ID and purchase_date:

```
select id, count(*) from test group by id having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: And I don't think that you could simplify your inner query as in `select distinct cast(A.when as date) as purchase_date, A.id from purchase A)`, or not?

Comment: if he'll group only by the id, he'll get only one date per id, that's not what he likes

Comment: So that the full query would be
`select id, count(*) from (select distinct cast(A.when as date) as purchase_date, A.id from purchase A) B group by id having count(*) > 1`

Comment: @NirLevy, `test` was the inner query, not the original table.

Comment: select B.id, count( * ) from (select cast(A.when as date) as purchase_date, A.id from purchase A group by cast(A.when as date), A.id order by A.id) B group by B.id having count(*)>1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are grouping by both id and the date. when you do that, it doesn't matter if you do `having count(id)`, the grouping is already done and the `having` we'll be against both columns.

You need another sub query with the id's that appear more than once, and use `A.id in (...)`